# What is wrong with my summation solution to this integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

Okay so I am a calculus student and found the following integration problem:
$$\int f(x)f'(x) dx$$
Through integration by parts the solution is...
$$\frac{f^2(x)}{2}+C$$
Pretty cool problem. Next I thought why not try $\int f(x)f''(x)dx$?
So I did that and through two applications of integration by parts I am left with the identity 0=0. Not helpful. I move on to $\int f(x)f'''(x)dx$. Two applications of integration by parts proves more useful here, I get the solution
$$f(x)f''(x)-\frac{[f'(x)]^2}{2}+C$$
So at this point all the by partsing is leaving me pretty lazy. I have the conjecture that given odd z in the following formula, integration by parts (however many times) will provide a nice solution and with even z trivial identities will result. I'm too lazy to go out beyond n=3 and just skipped to attempting to integrate this thing in full generality.
$$\int f(x)f^{(z)}(x)dx$$
So I keep integrating by parts over and over and over and I notice a pattern...
$$\int f(x)f^{(z)}(x)dx = f(x)f^{(z-1)}(x)-f'(x)f^{(z-2)}(x)+f''(x)f^{(z-3)}(x)-f'''(x)f^{(z-4)}(x)+...$$
Hmmmm. I came up with the following.
$$\int f(x)f^{(z)}(x)dx = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}[(-1)^nf^{(n)}(x)f^{(z-n-1)}(x)]$$
Upon testing the results are interesting. For z=1 and only one term you get
$$f^2(x)$$
Hmmmm, close but where did the 1/2 coefficient go? My guess is that in solving that original problem at the top of my post, its one of those integration by parts problems in which the second integral is also the problem's integral so you just solve for it and that is where the 1/2 pops out. So when using this series, that second integral never comes out as integration by parts is done forever, hence no 1/2.
For z=2 the results are interesting but I don't know where to stop as I haven't actually solved z=2. Moving on to z=3 I get
$$f(x)f''(x)-[f'(x)]^2$$
after two terms. Close to the solution but again missing the 1/2 coefficient, this time on the last term. So ultimately my question is what is wrong with my summation solution to the general integral? A. why can't I just add up all the terms to infinity to get my solution for any z instead of stopping and B. when I know at how many terms to stop why is the solution always off by the coefficient on the final term? I hate that this summation doesn't work even through it appears that it should. Maybe I am just dumb and making a stupid mistake.

Comment: The upper limit of $\infty$ is (the) bad idea. You get "derivatives of negative order". If you stop at $z=n-1$, you get your sum plus a remainder which (up to sign) is exactly the integral you've started with (on the LHS). Now, count up $2$'s ;)